# Checkboxes only on Leafs of TreeTableView in JavaFX

Tags: checkbox, javafx

I have a TreeTableIView with 3 levels. I want to show Checkboxes on leafs only, while all other cells remain empty. So far, I have created 2 columns:

The first column holds the hierarchy:

```
      TreeTableColumn<AttributeRow, String> attributeColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Attributes");
        attributeColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
        attributeColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<AttributeRow, String> param) -> 
                new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getAttributeName())
        );
```

The second columns shall contain the CheckBoxes on leafs only:

```
           TreeTableColumn<AttributeRow, Boolean> companyColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>(companyGroup);
           companyColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
           companyColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn(companyColumn));
           companyColumn.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
               if (param.getValue().getValue().getCompanyGroups() == null) {
                   return new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
               } else {                

                   return new SimpleBooleanProperty(false); 
               }
           });
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Is there a way to only show CheckBoxes on leafs, while the other cells are empty? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use a custom [`rowFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html#rowFactoryProperty) that checks, if the item it contains is a leaf or not and adds or removes a `leaf` pseudoclass:

```
private static final PseudoClass LEAF = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("leaf");

...

treeTableView.setRowFactory(view -> new TreeTableRow<BoolItem>() {

    {
        ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            pseudoClassStateChanged(LEAF, newValue);
        };
        treeItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            if (oldItem != null) {
                oldItem.leafProperty().removeListener(listener);
            }
            if (newItem != null) {
                newItem.leafProperty().addListener(listener);
                listener.changed(null, null, newItem.isLeaf());
            } else {
                listener.changed(null, null, Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Furthemore use a custom [`cellFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableColumn.html#cellFactoryProperty) that in addition to creating the cell also assigns a style class to it that allows you to identify it as a cell that should be hidden, if it's not a leaf:

```
companyColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<AttributeRow, Boolean> param) -> {
    CheckBoxTreeTableCell<AttributeRow, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTreeTableCell<>();
    cell.getStyleClass().add("hide-non-leaf");
    return cell;
});
```

This allows you to hide the appropriate cells from a CSS stylesheet:

```css
.tree-table-row-cell .hide-non-leaf * {
    /* invisible by default */
    visibility: hidden;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:leaf .hide-non-leaf * {
    /* make visible, if leaf */
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**Edit:** For some reason javafx seems to set the visibility of the cell inline, which overrides the CSS style. Therefore you the children of the cells are made invisible instead of the cells themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented your solution and it partly works. However, if one checkbox is clicked, it disappears while the checkbox above suddenly appears. So there is some strange behavior here.

Comment: @user41854 I couldn't reproduce that exact issue, but I found a most likely related one: For some reason `TreeTableView` seems to set the visibility of cells to `true` if cells are displayed again, thereby overriding the CSS style, which means after scrolling cells into view again, they become visible. Added a workaround (making the decendants of the cell invisible instead of the cell itself). The current version should work as of java 8u92.

Comment: Use `newItem.isLeaf() || newItem.getChildren().get(0).isLeaf()` if you want checkboxes on the 2 outer levels (leaf or parent of leaf)